# My analog speakers are picking up radio

Tags: usb, speakers

This has been happening for a while, and it's starting to drive me up the wall. It is very quiet, but can still be heard.

Is it possible the speakers are picking up radio, because they are older (like from 2007-ish) and they have analog cable, and not USB one?

EDIT: I specifically would like to know if it's possible the problem to be related to the nature of the cable (analog), and if USB cables would not have this problem.

Comment: This does look like a duplicate, but replying to that 5-year old thread seems moot.  One option I don't see mentioned there is the possibility that the user is picking up the ground wave of a nearby AM transmitter. You see that in telephony quite often.  If so, a good power strip with RF filtering on the ground prong may solve it.

Comment: Bad shielding, nearby potential for an antenna - easy to explain. Harder to fix, as it involves upgrading hardware with no certain knowledge of the actual component that's guilty.